# Apache James Custom Mailet with Async Processing

Tags: apache, james

We are trying to created a Pre-Processing logic for all outgoing messages. Is it possible to create an mailet to store the messages in QueueA/Repository as soon as the message is received which would be picked up by the pre-processing logic and move it to QueueB/Repository which would be picked up James for sending it to Recipient.

I am using Apache James 3.0.4-Beta

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When receiving a mail (SMTP / JMAP) James append it to the mail queue "SPOOL". (Understand ActiveMQ)

Then the "PreProcessing" is done on it. It's more routing, and mail modification logic. You can organize mailet (side effects and mail modification) and matcher (when to apply a mailet) in processors. As part of this, you can use the LocalDelivery mailet, for delivering them to the local mailbox of users. Or RemoteDelivery for sending it to distant users. RemoteDelivery will append it to an other queue that will be processed by an other pool of threads for sending the given e-mail. To go further, have a look to mailetcontainer.xml config file.

So IMO what you describe looks like the basic James behaviour...

Ah and PS, please use at least 3.0-beta6, or better, master branch ;-)

Cheers,

Benoit